# how do hide an image at runtime using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

In my html5 file in windows 8 modern app I have two image tags defined.name of the first image is previous and name of other image is next. When the application loads for the first time I want 'previous' image not to be displayed and 'next' image should be displayed.

I haven't assigned any source to both the images.and when the application loads for the first time I assigned some source to 'next' image and it loads successfully.but the 'previous' image icon with square shape is still shown.i want it to display nothing here.And also later point I want to hide the 'next' image completely.

in both the cases the square shape is shown when I am assigning no source.

any suggestions on how to hide the image so that nothing would be displayed in place of it.

Comment: Uh, set the display none property?`#my-image {display:none;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about setting their style.visibility attribute?

```
var mImg = document.getElementById('idOfFirstImage');
mImg.style.visibility = "hidden";

mImg = document.getElementById('idOfSecondImage');
mImg.style.visibility = 'visible';
```